# "No route matches" : Nightmare with routing rails namespace

Tags: namespaces, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm geting crazy with a namespace URL that leads to incorrect action 'show' instead of 'new'.

When I'm using this URL : **admin/admin_utilisateurs/new**
I get this **error** :

```
Routing Error
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/admin_utilisateurs"}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

This is the **link_to** I'm using in my index page :

```
link_to 'Nouveau', new_admin_admin_utilisateur_path, :class => 'btn-text btn-dimensions btn-encrusted metal'
```

These are my **rake routes** :

```
                                 root        /                                              welcome#index
                     pub_responsables GET    /catalogs/managers(.:format)                   pub_responsables#index
                                      POST   /catalogs/managers(.:format)                   pub_responsables#create
                  new_pub_responsable GET    /catalogs/managers/new(.:format)               pub_responsables#new
                 edit_pub_responsable GET    /catalogs/managers/:id/edit(.:format)          pub_responsables#edit
                      pub_responsable GET    /catalogs/managers/:id(.:format)               pub_responsables#show
                                      PUT    /catalogs/managers/:id(.:format)               pub_responsables#update
                                      DELETE /catalogs/managers/:id(.:format)               pub_responsables#destroy
        new_admin_utilisateur_session GET    /admin_utilisateurs/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#new
            admin_utilisateur_session POST   /admin_utilisateurs/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#create
    destroy_admin_utilisateur_session DELETE /admin_utilisateurs/sign_out(.:format)         devise/sessions#destroy
           admin_utilisateur_password POST   /admin_utilisateurs/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#create
       new_admin_utilisateur_password GET    /admin_utilisateurs/password/new(.:format)     devise/passwords#new
      edit_admin_utilisateur_password GET    /admin_utilisateurs/password/edit(.:format)    devise/passwords#edit
                                      PUT    /admin_utilisateurs/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#update
cancel_admin_utilisateur_registration GET    /admin_utilisateurs/cancel(.:format)           admin_utilisateurs/registrations#cancel
       admin_utilisateur_registration POST   /admin_utilisateurs(.:format)                  admin_utilisateurs/registrations#create
   new_admin_utilisateur_registration GET    /admin_utilisateurs/sign_up(.:format)          admin_utilisateurs/registrations#new
  edit_admin_utilisateur_registration GET    /admin_utilisateurs/edit(.:format)             admin_utilisateurs/registrations#edit
                                      PUT    /admin_utilisateurs(.:format)                  admin_utilisateurs/registrations#update
                                      DELETE /admin_utilisateurs(.:format)                  admin_utilisateurs/registrations#destroy
       admin_utilisateur_confirmation POST   /admin_utilisateurs/confirmation(.:format)     devise/confirmations#create
   new_admin_utilisateur_confirmation GET    /admin_utilisateurs/confirmation/new(.:format) devise/confirmations#new
                                      GET    /admin_utilisateurs/confirmation(.:format)     devise/confirmations#show
             admin_utilisateur_unlock POST   /admin_utilisateurs/unlock(.:format)           devise/unlocks#create
         new_admin_utilisateur_unlock GET    /admin_utilisateurs/unlock/new(.:format)       devise/unlocks#new
                                      GET    /admin_utilisateurs/unlock(.:format)           devise/unlocks#show
             admin_admin_utilisateurs GET    /admin/admin_utilisateurs(.:format)            admin/admin_utilisateurs#index
                                      POST   /admin/admin_utilisateurs(.:format)            admin/admin_utilisateurs#create
          new_admin_admin_utilisateur GET    /admin/admin_utilisateurs/new(.:format)        admin/admin_utilisateurs#new
         edit_admin_admin_utilisateur GET    /admin/admin_utilisateurs/:id/edit(.:format)   admin/admin_utilisateurs#edit
              admin_admin_utilisateur GET    /admin/admin_utilisateurs/:id(.:format)        admin/admin_utilisateurs#show
                                      PUT    /admin/admin_utilisateurs/:id(.:format)        admin/admin_utilisateurs#update
                                      DELETE /admin/admin_utilisateurs/:id(.:format)        admin/admin_utilisateurs#destroy
```

For info, I'm using Devise on a users table which I called "admin_utilisateurs".
Devise is working great with options : :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, :recoverable, :registerable, :trackable, :timeoutable, :validatable, :lockable

The point is that I setup another controller for admin purpose on the admin_utilisateurs table.

So here it is my **config/routes.rb**

```
  root :to => 'welcome#index'

  resources :pub_responsables, :path =>'/catalogs/managers'

  devise_for :admin_utilisateurs, :controllers => {:registrations => 'admin_utilisateurs/registrations'}

  namespace :admin do
    resources :admin_utilisateurs
  end
```

So my admin controller is located in **app/controllers/admin/admin_utilisateurs_controller.rb**

Here is the action of my **'new'** controller's action :

```
class Admin::AdminUtilisateursController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_admin_utilisateur!

  ...

  def new
    @admin_utilisateur = AdminUtilisateur.new
    respond_with(@admin_utilisateur)
  end

  ...
end
```

The view for that controller are located in app/view/admin/admin_utilisateurs/

But the issue is really connected to the route because the other path for 'show', 'edit' and 'update' are working properly.

And if I delete my controller app/controllers/admin/admin_utilisateurs_controller.rb, Rails is not complaining about missing controller, she's still complaining about the "no route for show action".

I'm really lost. Could anyone advise please ?
Thanks in advance

**===== UPDATE 1 =====**

Here it is the log related to my URL request :

```
Started GET "/admin/admin_utilisateurs/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-25 12:55:05 +0200
Processing by Admin::AdminUtilisateursController#new as HTML
  Rendered shared/_main_title.html.haml (0.4ms)
  Rendered admin/admin_utilisateurs/_form.html.haml (17.2ms)
  Rendered admin/admin_utilisateurs/new.html.haml within layouts/application (31.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 45ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/admin_utilisateurs"}):
  app/views/admin/admin_utilisateurs/_form.html.haml:1:in `_app_views_admin_admin_utilisateurs__form_html_haml___780348754_85631840'
  app/views/admin/admin_utilisateurs/new.html.haml:9:in `_app_views_admin_admin_utilisateurs_new_html_haml__296364877_85537950'
  app/controllers/admin/admin_utilisateurs_controller.rb:51:in `new'
```

It seems that it is properly routed but then there is a problem in the view.

I retried to remove the controller file admin_utilisateurs_controller.rb **but this time restart my web server** (sudo service apache2 restart) and the error was different.
I got this time a "Routing error uninitialized constant Admin::AdminUtilisateursController".

So this confrim there is an issue in my view...
digging deeper...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the issue.
The issue was coming from my partial form view which I use for my 'edit' action and for my 'new' action : /app/views/admin/admin_utilisateurs/_form.html.haml

```
= form_for @admin_utilisateur, :url => admin_admin_utilisateur_path, :html => {:class => "formulaire-standard"} do |f|

  = render :partial => 'shared/error_message', :locals => { :element => @admin_utilisateur, :debut_erreur => 'Cet utilisateur ne peut être enregistré'}

  .groupe-champs
    .champ
      = f.label :nom
      = f.text_field :nom, :class => 'input-width-8-col', :required => 'required'
    .champ
      = f.label :prenom
      = f.text_field :prenom, :class => 'input-width-5-col', :required => 'required'
    .champ
      = f.label :telephone
      = f.telephone_field :telephone, :class => 'input-width-5-col', :required => 'required'
    .champ
      = f.label :mobile
      = f.telephone_field :mobile, :class => 'input-width-5-col'
    .champ
      = f.label :email
      = f.email_field :email, :class => 'input-width-8-col', :required => 'required'

  .groupe-champs
    = render :partial => 'shared/checkboxes_admin_utilisateur', :locals => { :resource => @admin_utilisateur }


  .groupe-champs
    .champ-1
      = f.check_box :approved
    .champ-5
      = f.label :approved
    .checkbox-explication
      = t('activerecord.attributes.admin_utilisateur.explanations.active')

  .separator

  .groupe-actions
    = f.submit 'Enregistrer', :class => 'btn-text btn-dimensions btn-encrusted metal'
    = link_to 'Annuler', admin_admin_utilisateur_path, :class => 'btn-text btn-dimensions btn-encrusted metal'
```

I was using the form_for tag incorrectly. Because my form is used within a namespace, I must add the namespace into its arguments, and remove the :url option because otherwise this form will only work with the 'edit' action :

```
= form_for [:admin, @admin_utilisateur], :html => {:class => "formulaire-standard"} do |f|
```

This code lets Rails guess what path to use wether it's for a new record or to edit an existing record. So I don't need to specify the :url and the :method.

The second mistake was (a classical one) the link_to at the bottom of the form.
I forgot the 's' at the end of the route helper (admin_admin_utilisateurSSSS_path):

```
= link_to 'Annuler', admin_admin_utilisateurs_path, :class => 'btn-text btn-dimensions btn-encrusted metal'
```

## The moral of the story :

**ALLWAYS CHECK YOUR /log/development.log FILE !** ;-)